# Central Limit Theorem: asymptotic distribution

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

I keep reading in the documents about the asymptotic distribution of the CLT. I am learning things by myself so try to figure it out on my own and don't have a teacher to ask the question to.

So it's my understanding that the variance of the sample mean is:

$Var(\bar X) = {{ \sigma^2 } \over { n }}.$

I also know that you can write this variance as $E[(\bar X - \mu)^2]$ where $\bar X$ is the sample mean and $\mu$ is the population mean. you can definitely plot the first equation (if you know the population variance $\sigma^2$) and yes you would get a curve which is going very close to the x-axis (without even touching it); this my understanding of what they "asymptotic" word means.

[image]

I am trying to understand if this is what it means when I find in text books that the CLT has an asymptotic distribution? Could someone explained a bit more what it means when one says that "the Central Limit Theorem provides the asymptotic distribution of $\sqrt{N}(\bar X − \mu)$"?

Thank you very much.

Comment: `this my understanding of what they "asymptotic" word means"` That is quite different for the intended meaning here.

Comment: @leonbloy. Could you please tell me a bit more. I don't need a long explanation just pointers eventually to what I should be looking for. I really need help on this, as I feel stuck. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the variance of $\bar X_n$ goes to zero when $n\to\infty$ (like $\sigma^2/n$) indicates that $\bar X_n$ looks more and more like the constant random variable equal to $E[\bar X_n]=\mu$. The CLT is a second order expansion of $\bar X_n$ around $\mu$. The surprise, when one first sees this result, is that the convergence of $\bar X_n-\mu$ suitably normalized happens *in distribution* (but not in probability, even less almost surely).

At the end of the day, the CLT is a relatively weak statement saying, first, that the correct normalization is $\sqrt{n}$ (not a surprise if one wants the variance to converge to a positive finite limit) and, second, that $Z_n=\sqrt{n}(\bar X_n-\mu)$ converges in distribution to a normal random variable $Z$ with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$. This means that, for every real number $z$,
$$
P[Z_n\leqslant z]\to P[Z\leqslant z].
$$
Since one knows the distribution of $Z$, one knows that the value of the RHS is
$$
P[Z\leqslant z]=\int_{-\infty}^{x/\sigma}\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathrm e^{-t^2/2}\mathrm dt.
$$
Note that the almost sure behaviour of $Z_n$ is another matter, since $\limsup\limits_{n\to+\infty}Z_n=+\infty$ and $\liminf\limits_{n\to+\infty}Z_n=-\infty$, almost surely (a keyword here being *law of iterated logarithm*).

To sum up, the fact that the variance is $\sigma^2/n$ suggests the normalization in the CLT but the CLT itself is a much more encompassing result. For example, the fact that a *unique* distribution (the normal one) captures the behaviour of *every* $\bar X_n$ (provided square integrability) should be truly bewildering.

Comment: Sorry I edited the post and removed the $\sqrt{}$.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is almost too smart for me. Can I re-write what I understand in plain english;-) and could please tell me if I get it more or less right? In other words, $\sqrt{n}(\bar X - \mu)$ is used to normalise whatever distribution we have (which we know is a normal distribution which is what the CLT states), to a normal distribution with mean 0 and variance $\sigma^2)$. As N become very large, the curve of the "normal distribution" becomes tighter and higher, but this normalization factor helps to always "bring this curve back" to one which is always the same?  ...

Comment: Not quite. In most situations, no random variable $\sqrt{n}(\bar X_n-\mu)$ is gaussian.

Comment: (continued), then you suggest in the second part that because we now know the distribution of this normal distribution with mean 0 and variance $\sigma^2$ it becomes easier to compute for instance the probability that z is greater or equal than Z? Finally, you suggest that when n tends to plus or minus infinity $Z_n$ also becomes plus or minus infinity and that then making such calculation as what is the probability that $z \ge Z_n$ is undefined in behaviour? It would be great if you could also confirm my understanding of what the word "asymptotic" means in this context? Do I get it right?

Comment: Your comment is quite far from what I actually wrote. For example, where you saw a limit $n\to-\infty$ eludes me. As any reason why the probability that $Z_n\geqslant z$ would be "undefined in behaviour" *although I explicitely say that it converges*. In any case, "asymptotic" (which does NOT appear in my answer) can only mean "in the limit $n\to+\infty$".

Comment: Okay, thank you. It seems like I need to acquire more knowledge before I can fully understand the meaning of your answer. Thanks for your time.